# why memory for primitive data types is not allocated?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory, memory-management, primitive-types

Primitive data types such as char, bool and int have some memory. Suppose char, which has 1 byte of memory. When we use a char variable in our code, then the variable must require 1 byte of memory. Why don't we allocate memory in this case. And as we never allocate memory for it, how does it use the memory ,i.e. Is the CPU allocate memory for it in this case.Also I read somewhere that the primitive data types are put on stack and removed when the work is done for it. What kind of stack? How does the stack comes into picture in this case?

Comment: The stack and the heap are different types of memory. Your question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Answer (score 5):

When we create an `NSString *` variable, we don't allocate the memory for this either.

We only allocate memory when `alloc` is called, either directly by us or inside a method we call.

An `NSString` object exists on the heap in memory we've allocated, but the `NSString *` variable (which is, a pointer to an `NSString` object) exists in memory on the stack which we do not allocate.

For example, given these two variables:

```
NSString *stringOne;
NSString *stringTwo;
```

So far, neither has been allocated any memory on the heap, although they do exist in memory in the exact same way a `char`, `BOOL`, or `int` exists in memory.

```
NSString *stringOne = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"];
NSString *stringTwo = stringOne;
```

Now what has happened?  We allocated some memory on the heap for an `NSString` object.  We then initialized this memory to represent the string "Hello world" and then returned a pointer to this object and assigned it to `stringOne`.

Next, we simply copied that pointer over into the stack memory we're using for `stringTwo`.  We didn't allocate any extra memory on the heap.  We simply made our two string variable point to the same allocated memory on the heap.

The [question and answer jsd linked in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap?lq=1) has more explanation on stack and heap memory which will answer some of your questions.

It's also worth noting that a lot of other programming languages such as C++ allow objects to be created on the stack, in which case we don't allocate them, as we would with heap objects.  They do exist in memory, just more similarly to primitive data types.

Comment: Right... one implementation detail of relevant interest (but, by no means, invalidates the answer in anyway);  `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"]` won't actually create a string on the heap.  It'll just return the __NSCFConstantString (or whatever it is called) that was laid down in the mach-o file by the compiler.  It is merely an interesting detail in that it does not change anything about your consumption of said string;  it should be treated just like any other object.

Comment: I guess the example is probably better with mutable objects where it's more important that they be on the heap because their size needs to be able to change.

Answer (score 5):

At the risk of being over simplistic, there are three classes of memory for data: 1) static, 2) stack 3) heap.

They are allocated in different ways.

if you have

```
 static char something ;
```

defined in a function or

```
char something ;
```

outside of a function, that data is defined by the linker using instructions from the compiler and allocated by the program loaders.

Nearly every processor in existence uses a stack to support nested data (e.g., function calls). The stack is a block of memory that exists for every process (and for every processor mode). There is a a hardware register called the Stack Pointer that identifies the current position of the stack. Usually the SP starts at the high end of the stack and works downward. To allocate memory on the stack, the program subtracts the number of bytes required from the stack pointer. To deallocate, it adds to the stack pointer. The allocations and deallocations always take place at the same end.

There are then two operations on the stack. PUSH means put something on the stack. POP removes it. Most processors have instructions to PUSH and POP

If you have

```
 char something
```

defined within a function, that memory is allocated by the program as directed by the compiler by doing something like this to adjust the stack pointer (I'm leaving out a frame pointer for now)

```
 SUB   BYTESNEEDED, SP
```

upon entering the function and freed by doing

```
ADD BYTESNEEDED, SP
```

before leaving the function. During the execution of the function, the local variables are at offsets from the stack pointer.

This usually done by using a second register, usually called a frame pointer. A function usually does something like this at the start

```
PUSH  FP       ; Save the old Frame Point 
MOV   SP  FP   ; Save the stack pointer
SUB   BYTESNEEDED, SP
```

at the end the function does something like

MOV  FP, SP  ; Free all the stack allocated by the function
   POP  FP      ; Restore the old stack pointer

The reason for using two registers is that it is possible to dynamically allocate data from the stack.

THere is a common function (although I believe it is not a standard C function) called alloca that is an alternative to malloc that allocates from the stack

```
void dosomething (int amount)
{
    char *data = alloca (amount) ;
}
```

With alloca, the data is automatically freed when the function returns and resets the stack.

That is a long winded answer to your question. Yes, when declare a char, there has to be an allocation for it. However, this allocation is done behind the scenes without effort on your part.