# NSString Address issue

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to print address to string but i'm getting different address in first NSLog & same address in second NSLog. So could you tell me how is this happing. Its really confusing me. Thanks a lot in advance for your efforts.

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *str2 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *str3 = [[NSString alloc] init];

NSLog(@"str1 = %p , str2 = %p, str3 = %p",&str1,&str2,&str3);
NSLog(@"str1 = %p , str2 = %p, str3 = %p",str1,str2,str3);
```

**Output**

```
str1 = 0x7fff565b9c88 , str2 = 0x7fff565b9c80, str3 = 0x7fff565b9c78
str1 = 0x10c0a7060 , str2 = 0x10c0a7060, str3 = 0x10c0a7060
```

I don't understand why `str1`, `str2`, and `str3` all point to the same memory location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And why *should* `str1`, `str2`, `str3` all reside at different memory addresses?  They're all the same immutable string.

See [bbum's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726493/why-memory-for-primitive-data-types-is-not-allocated/23726795#comment36478269_23726795):

> Right... one implementation detail of relevant interest (but, by no means, invalidates the answer in anyway); **`[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello world"]` won't actually create a string on the heap. It'll just return the __NSCFConstantString (or whatever it is called) that was laid down in the mach-o file by the compiler.** It is merely an interesting detail in that it does not change anything about your consumption of said string; it should be treated just like any other object.

Emphasis mine.

What's going on here is that when the compiler can determine at compile time what an immutable `NSString` object will be, it's creating that string differently.  As bbum states, ultimately it's an implementation detail that you shouldn't worry about when you're writing your program.

But the side effect of this means that the compiler is able to make my program more memory efficient because it is able to find all of these instances and make all of my `NSString` pointers that it knows are supposed to be holding the same immutable value all point to the same single memory address.

We can probably achieve the same result with the following:

```
NSString *str1 = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSString *str2 = [NSString new];
NSString *str3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@""];
NSString *str4 = [NSString stringWithString:@""];
NSString *str5 = @"";
```

These are all effectively the same thing.

However, if we create another string:

```
NSString *str6 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @""];
```

This will (most likely... last time I checked) end up with a different value if we print `str6` as a pointer.

And there are other ways to generate immutable `NSString` objects that don't get optimized like this at compile time.  The point here is that if the compile can know at compile time what the string is going to be, it will create a `__NSCFConstantString` in the background that's outside of memory management, and it will point to that single instance whatever it can.  Once it gets to run time, it will only point anything else to this if you point it there directly (`str6 = str1`).  Otherwise, it's not going to waste execution time trying to determine if the strings are equal.  If a new `NSString` happens to be equal and it wasn't happened at compile time, it will just be handled by ARC.

The compiler isn't able to determine that `str6` is the same immutable string as the others.  This is only a build time implication that the others all ended up with the same address.

Another interesting thing to note is that you will never see `dealloc` called on the `__NSCFConstantString` the compiler is creating for the variables declared in the way you declared them.  So the compiler is not only making your code more efficient from a memory stand point, it's also removing *all* of the memory management code involved in keeping up with these strings.

Answer (score 2):

The first call to NSLog is printing the addresses of the 3 local variables str1, str2 and str3. They are all residing on the stack because they are local, hence the large addresses.

The second NSLog call is printing the addresses of the objects *pointed to* by str1, str2 and str3, which in this case has been optimised to the same object.

Your local variables are already pointers to NSStrings, not actual NSStrings themselves, so you don't need the address operator &.

Answer (score 1):

Thats interesting that you got the result but makes sense str1, str2, str3 are all immutable and so they will never change and all have the same contents, so instead of getting 3 new NSString you have just got the same one three times. If you change them to NSMutableStrings you will get the result you expected. I played around with this a little more and I found if you turn of ARC and add this

```
NSLog(@"str1 = %lu , str2 = %lu, str3 = %lu",
           [str1 retainCount], [str2 retainCount], [str3 retainCount] );
```

you get some more interesting stuff, I was expecting to see the value 3, three times to represent the three allocs for the same object but instead you get 18446744073709551615, which makes sense when you also add this

```
NSLog(@"str1 = %@ , str2 = %@, str3 = %@",
                        [str1 class], [str2 class], [str3 class] );
```

You will see the class is __NSCFConstantString which is not reference counted its the equivalent to c literal string.

You can get a similar thing with a lot of c compilers where if you define a literal c string like

```
    char    * cstr1 = "abc";
    char    * cstr2 = "abc";

    printf( "cstr1 == cstr2 = %s\n", cstr1 == cstr2 ? "true" : "false" );
```

You can see the compiler has save memory for literals by only having one "abc" and pointing all pointers to the same place.

Thinking about it a little more the init method for NSString may look something like this

```
- (instancetype)init {
    [self release];
    return @"";
}
```

Comment: You told str1,str2 & str3 all are immutable but according to my opinion it should be print different address because we are creating different instance.

Comment: You don't know what is being eventually created, the alloc init pattern usually allocates and returns a new object but it doesn't have to, as in my init example the original object is probable being released and a constant string is returned instead. This is why we alway assign the result of [super init] to self in init methods in case the super class returns a different object to the one we started with. This lets you do interesting things like singletons, or one unique instance per some key value etc.

Comment: I don't always `[self release]`, but when I do, there is `[super init]`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but you should never use the result of alloc past the init method because of situations like I have shown.

Answer (score 0):

str1 is the memory address of the string

&str1 is the memory address of the pointer to the string

(could be the other way round)

Comment: But why second nslog printing same result.

Comment: I guess, as the strings are immutable anyway the same memory address is used.

Comment: But we created different instance of NSString. So it should print different address because it taking memory on different address.

Comment: yes, the pointer addresses are different but they point to the same memory address (which reveals that `&str` is the memory address). This is safe because the strings are immutable

Comment: This answer is quite incomplete.  The question doesn't ask what the values represent, but rather why all three pointers point to the same address.