# Pass same data from one VC to another VC to another VC

Tags: swift, option-type, uistoryboardsegue, forced-unwrapping

I have a variable named name with string "Magellan" that needs to be added to each VC's nameLabel.

In first VC:

```
var name = "Magellan"
```

First VC prepare for segue:

```
destination?.nameLabel.text = name!
destination?.name = name!
```

In second VC:

```
var name = String()
```

Second VC prepare for segue:

```
destination?.nameLabel.text = name!
destination?.name = name!
```

In second VC to go to third VC:

```
Error: Unexpectedly found nil unwrapping nameLabel.text
Error: Unexpectedly found nil unwrapping name
```

Comment: Error says `nameLabel` & `name` variable are nil in destination VC, which means your Third VC is not initialised with all the properties when this assignment happens. I believe it would fix the problem

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: As i said your third VC is not initialised, check why it’s not initialised

Comment: Ah yes, it was flawed because there wasn't a variable that held the name of anything in third VC. I added a variable to third and it worked just fine. thank s\

Answer (score -1):

you have to change your

```
var name = String()
```

to

```
var name : String = “”
```

the difference of this is when you used the **var name = String()** you are assigning *String class* to your variable name while for **var name : String = “”** you are assigning *empty value* to your string type variable name.

Comment: Check this [Swift string via string literal vs initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197008/swift-string-via-string-literal-vs-initializer)