# What is the difference between var testID = String() and var testID : String = ""

Tags: swift, string

I want to declare a variable of type string, as mentioned in question both ways work. Want to know the difference when to use each one specifically

```
var testID = String() 
var testID : String = ""
```

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift string via string literal vs initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31197008/swift-string-via-string-literal-vs-initializer)